# Delete large amount of directories under a top level

Tags: bash, directory, rm

I have a directory full of several other directories with the same structure, so it looks like this

```
top/A/Output/platform/..
top/B/Output/platform/..
top/C/Output/platform/..
```

and so on. I want to, starting from the `top` level, delete all the directories downwards of the `platform` directories, such that I end up with

```
top/A/Output
top/B/Output
top/C/Output
```

Can anyone recommend me a command for this? I am on rhel7 with bash 4.1.2

EDIT:

I have a lot of '2nd level' directories whose names are more complex than single letters, sorry should have noted that more explicitly

Comment: Something like `rm -rf top/[ABC]/Output/platform` maybe?

Comment: If any of the existing answers solved your problem, please consider accepting it with the checkmark; thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
rm -rf top/?/Output/platform
```

or, if the 2nd-level directory may be more than one character (A, B, or C in your example):

```
rm -rf top/*/Output/platform
```

Comment: This works because Bash, like all shells, interprets `?` as “any single character in a filename” and `*` as “any sequence of characters in a filename” (note that this is “filename”, not “path”; they don’t match `/`).

Comment: Note that the star (*) won't match directories and files which start with a dot.

Answer (score 0):

See `man find` for more options like regex patterns:

```
find top -type d -name platform -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Comment: Will unfortunately also delete any other `platform` directory elsewhere, not just under `top/*/Output`.

Comment: @Kusalananda That's right, I have forgot the working directory. Thank you for your note.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find this way :

```
find top -path 'top/*/Output/platform' -delete
```

Note that this will delete file and directories which start with a dot.

The following command won't delete files and directories starting with a dot, because the shell will skip them when it replaces the stars :

```
rm top/*/Output/platform
```